# Hosting RASA NLU Model on Cloud Server

Tags: python, server, host, aiml, rasa

I am working on a voice assistant using RASA NLU that will be later deployed on an android/IOS mobile app. I currently have a python program, where I call the RASA NLU model and parse incoming input using the Interpreter class.

```
interpreter = Interpreter.load("training_data/models/nlu/default/current/")
interpreter.parse(input)
```

The answer I get is stored in a JSON object where I parse this to get the intent + associated entities. I later take this output and use an AIML interpreter to get the corresponding response for it. I store all the responses in AIML files.

My problem is now that all of this code runs locally on my machine. I want to load my RASA NLU model on a server and then use some kind of APIs to request a response from the model and send it to the AIML kernel (also stored on the server). The model should always be running on the server, and I will be sending requests from the mobile app. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this is too broad/vague. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I would advise removing the aiml tag in your question, as it seems more network related than AIML.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first do a Rasa X deployment to your server, as is described in the documentation at rasa.com.

Once you got that working, then create a custom connector that hits the HTTP-API of Rasa Open Source.